# Starting activitys from a class library via intent on monodroid don't work (Mono for android)

Tags: android, android-activity, mono, xamarin.android

I created a Solution with:

- 1 android application (com.company.myapp)
- 1 android class library (com.company.products)

My ideia is to separate all the "products" logic and UI on this class library, and so on (one class library for clients, one class library for sales....etc).
And call UIs (Activitys) and othes classes from those class library from each other.

That said, when I try to call the activity from the other class library (com.company.products.ui.productsList.cs), it shows me a transition animation and come back to the main activity (com.company.products.ui.main.cs).

The code I use to call the activity from the class library is:

```
 Intent listaPedidos = new Intent(this, typeof(com.seiv4.pedido.UI.listaPedidos));
 StartActivity(listaPedidos);
```

I tried use:

```
new Intent(this, com.seiv4.pedido.UI.listaPedidos.class);
```

But visual studio "thinks" I'm trying to create a new class and expect some {}

Any hope will be appreciated.
If you guys need some more code, let me know, but my example is realy simple. Just one activity calling another one from a referenced class library.

ps: Sorry my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the listaPedidos code is hitting an error during startup.  Check the Android Debug Log for an error message:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log